# Displays the brand in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics when you create a transaction, you specify the parameters for the products. One of them is 'brand'. Where do I find this option in reports?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can't find "Product Brand" in the Google Analytics interface.

First of all, [make sure you have Enhanced Ecommerce enabled](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6032539?hl=en).

Then, on the left menu of your Google Analytics interface :

- Conversions -> Ecommerce -> Product Performance

You land on the product performance report. From there, just over the top of the table, you can select your Primary Dimension.

Pick "Product Brand" and you will see your products sales split by brand.